# File system info - how to query it?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

Is there a way to access file system info via some type of Windows API? If not what other methods are available to a user mode developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clean, but you can use `DeviceIoControl()`
Open volume as a file, pass resulting handle to `DeviceIoControl()` together with control code. Check MSDN for control codes, there is something like "read journal record".

Answer (score 0):

In another post, someone recommended this : [Keeping an Eye on Your NTFS Drives: the Windows 2000 Change Journal Explained](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/journal/journal.aspx).

It explains how to use the NTFS Filesystem with C++ through Windows 2000.
The implementation might have changed.